# undesired jump in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have copied some text into ms word. Now, what I am observing is that some lines doesnt complete properly. even there is a white space after the line it jumps to the next line. Also each line finishes un-evenly, that is, for the the last word of a line, some letters are in the line and remaining would go the next line. For example if I consider the word "finish" say, fin will be in a particular line and ish will starts with a new line. how to fix all these?

Comment: Paste the original text into Notepad to see what's actually there. It could be that it was broken like that originally and simply has to be fixed by hand.

Comment: See also: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CleanWebText.htm.